# Adding space between two displays of df in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How to add more space between the two dataframes display

```
from Ipython.display import display

display(df_a)
display(df_b)
```

Comment: just print an empty line in between print("")

Comment: By the way, if you use one of the latest Jupyter versions, you don't have to import `display`, it is already available.

Answer (score 0):

Although *display* is already imported in the base so you don't have to do that explicitly, you can use *HTML* to display a break line with '\n', see example below:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
display(df_a, HTML('\n'))
display(df_b)
```

It will produce an empty break line between the contents of the two DataFrames